# Maximum number of edges in a (n,n) bipartite graph, that doens't have a complete bipartite subgraph $K_{r,r}$

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I need to prove that the maximum number of edges in a $n \times n$ bipartite graph, that doens't have a complete bipartite subgraph $K_{r,r}$ is lower bounded by $cn^{2-2/(r+1)}$ where c is a constant that can only depend on r and not on n.

I know this problem is related with probabilistic proofs, and I am trying to find the expected number of edges in a bipartite graph ($n \times n$) that is in a graph with such stated property because I think that the $n^2$ part is probably related to "for all possible edges in the graph", but I can't go on with the proof.

Any hints? :)

Thanks.

Comment: There's a trivial solution: let $c=0$. If $r=1$ then that's tight.

Comment: I got what you said, but I must to prove for every $r \leq n$.

Comment: $c=0$ works for every $r$.

Comment: Yes, now that you said, I realized that it works for every $c \leq 0$. I think that it is supposed to be a positive number probably, but there is nothing stated about that. I'll ask the professor about it.

Thanks by now :)